# WPF SplashControl - > Login Page - > Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to build logic for start application. Splash control need for load data, but user can login, while data loaded.

```
        private void SplashControl_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StausLabel.Content = "Loading Data...";
        ShowLoginContinueLoading();
    }

    private void ShowLoginContinueLoading()
    {
        var loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            Managers.LoadUsers();
        });
        task.ContinueWith(async innerTask =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(loginWindow.Show);
            try
            {
                Managers.LoadData();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => StausLabel.Content = "Loading Complite");
        });

        task.Start();
```

How SlashControl can know login successful or not?

Comment: `LoginWindow` could raise an event that `SplashControl` listens for

Comment: This is a good situation where an event aggregator would work. When log on is completed you publish a log on complete event and anyone subscribed will know that this is complete.

Comment: @TYY I agree with that, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) is a pretty nice tutorial on how to do it.